# Can I plant cilantro with roots on it that I bought in the grocery section of a store?

Tags: growth, herbs, cilantro

I bought this cilantro in the grocery department of a large store. As you can see in the picture below, it still has roots attached. (I can post a clearer picture if you want.)

Would it start growing if I plant it in a container?

[image]

Comment: Likely easier to go to the local Arab or Asian store and buy some whole coriander seeds. I use Ziyad brand. They have a high germination rate, and turn into lovely cilantro plants. Should you manage to get your cilantro cuttings to work, they'll likely flower and go to seed soon; producing coriander.

Answer (score 2):

It's a somewhat borderline case.

For those plants that have just a bit of the top roots left, you probably won't be able to plant them with success. But I also see some longer roots and what looks like one plant with a slightly more complete root system. As a gardener, I would seriously be tempted to try and plant this specimen.

If you do so, make sure you reduce the number of  leaves significantly, because the plant won't be able to draw enough water and nutrition from the soil.

I suggest you *use* most of the greens, leaving the core intact, and plant the remaining roots in free-draining potting soil or into your garden beds. Note that a bright spot indoors might be a better choice right now, outside you need to protect the plants from too much sunlight initially. And if you decide to give it a go, do so as fast as possible, at minimum remove the leaves or they will draw water and "energy" from the roots - which is actually the reason that this cilantro was sold like this.

Note that cilantro is a somewhat short-term herb:
It has a tendency to bloom and set seeds after just a few weeks, and once it has grown its seeds, the plant has completed its life cycle and dies. So if you were hoping for a long-lived plant companion, this won't happen. But you can still get more leaves and ultimately seeds (for the kitchen and/or more plants) if you manage to get the roots to grow.

Comment: I would first place in water to enlarge the roots OR use the cilantro greens and only plant the roots with a bit of the top growth, 2 or 3 inches.  Best and easiest way is to just start with seed.  Always purchase seed that says, 'NON GMO'...

Comment: Yes you did...I don't read these things THAT closely sometimes...I just got done with a LONG horsey ride and am whooped.  Grins.  Of COURSE you said that...did I say something to challenge that?  I hope not!  Huggs...!!!

Comment: I've rooted cilantro in water but it never transplanted successfully for me.  I wouldn't bother trying to plant these.

Comment: Seriously.  Cilantro is easily grown, but my goodness it bolts so quickly!  Just too cold or too hot sends it on its way to become corriander! Plants put in water are just for science or an interesting bit on the window sill in front of the sink where we spend oh so much time! Water roots, soil roots are two different things...

Comment: @Stephie My words did not communicate properly, otherwise you would have understood, 'tis my fault!!  Please, always question my answers, please.  This is why I am here!  To check my knowledge, add to it and learn how to communicate with words only. Huggs